# Does "correct" have a comparative (or superlative) form? If it does, should it be "more correct" or "correcter"?

Tags: word-usage

Does "correct" have a comparative (or superlative) form? If does, should it be "more correct" or "correcter"?

For example，can I say，“Which sentence is more correct(or correcter)？”

I guess native speakers don't say that, but I still want to get an answer from native speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Correct' adjective has both comparative and superlative forms. They are '**more correct**' and '**most correct**' respectively.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correct) has an entry for this.

I am not a native speaker, but I can't find a word 'correcter' as a comparative form of 'correct' in any dictionary.

Comment: It's semantical reasons why you don't run into the comparative and superlative often.

Answer (score 3):

It is "*more correct*" (and the superlative is "*most correct*").  Those are the correcter forms.  Because **"*correcter" is *not* a valid construct**.

I need a correct**o**r to come and correct this post wherever I have **wrongly used** "*correcter*"

Answer (score 1):

If any, the comparative and the superlative forms of correct are "more correct" and "the most correct". However they  sound funny since there is nothing more than correctness and there will not be the most correct thing off all correct things. When something is declared correct, it is not comparable to any other correct thing.

Comment: Agreed (to a degree). It's almost like saying something is "more perfect".